# Getting Facebook page events purely via JavaScript SDK for all users, including those not logged in to Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, authentication, access-token

I'm working on including a list of events posted to a Facebook Page on my website.  The catch is that I'm trying to find a purely client-side JavaScript way of doing it.  I am unable to use PHP.  I may be able to use ASP.NET but I am struggling with the Facebook C# SDK's severe lack of documentation.  I have nearly a perfect implementation of what I want to do in JavaScript, however:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

$(document).ready(function(){

FB.init({ 
    appId: 'MY_APP_ID',cookie: true,xfbml: true,status: true });
    var token;
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        // Get and parse list of upcoming events
        $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/mypagename/events?access_token="+token+"&callback=?",function(json){
            for (item in json.data) {
                $("#eventsFromFacebook").append('<h3><a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/' +json.data[item].id +'/">' +json.data[item].name + '</a></h3>');
                $("#eventsFromFacebook").append('<strong>' +json.data[item].start_time +'</strong>');
                getItemDescription(json.data[item].id);     
                $("#eventsFromFacebook").append("<div id='event"+json.data[item].id+"'></div>");
            }
        });

        // Get and parse event descriptions. This is a separate call for each event.
        function getItemDescription(id) {
            $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"?access_token="+token+"&callback=?",function(jsonItem) {
            $("#event"+id).html('<p>' +jsonItem.description+'</p>');
            });
        }

        } else {
            // not logged in
            $("#eventsFromFacebook").append("Not getting access to Facebook :(");
        }
    });
});
```

(This requires FB JS SDK, jQuery and the following HTML:)

```
<div id="eventsFromFacebook"></div>
```

As is, this code successfully pulls the events posted on a specific Page I admin and posts them on my website, under the condition that I am logged into Facebook using the account connected to both the App and Page.  However, if I am not logged in as a person that has authenticated with my App, I can't get the right access to be able to do this.

Is there a purely JavaScript way to allow me to get the access token I need to get event information from a Page *when I am not logged in*?  I don't want to require users to authenticate with my App on my website to be able to see the information.  Ideally, I would like them to be able to see the events list without being logged into any Facebook account.  Is this possible?

If this isn't possible, as a fallback option, would there be a way to allow users who have liked the Page (without authenticating with the App) to at least see events?  That way, at least I can throw a link to my Facebook page in the event that someone isn't logged into Facebook (or give them an incentive to like the Page).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a purely JavaScript way to allow me to get the access token I
>   need to get event information from a Page when I am not logged in? I
>   don't want to require users to authenticate with my App on my website
>   to be able to see the information. Ideally, I would like them to be
>   able to see the events list without being logged into any Facebook
>   account. Is this possible?

Yes, it will be possible, HOWEVER not recommended as you will expose a page access token client-side.

What you do is first get you admin user's user access token.  Then extend it to the 60 day variety. Then HTTP Get to `me/accounts/PAGEID?fields=access_token&access_token=60DayUserAccessToken` and grab that access token (should be a 60 day variety, if not, call to extend it).  Use this access token client-side (ewe!! not good to expose this!!) to grab the page's events using `me/events?access_token=60DayPageAccessToken`.  Then every 59 days or so, you will have to generate a new 60 day access token to be included in your JavaScript (please, please don't do this as exposing your acccess token is really really bad).

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case.  If I were to find a way to use this token server-side would that allow anyone (not logged into Facebook) to successfully make that API call?